# phing installed but "not found" and not in pear list

Tags: php, installation, pear, propel, phing

I'm attempting to install the Propel ORM on CentOS which has a dependency for phing. I've run the following which was succesful:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
pear install phing/phing
pear install Log
```

However when I run `./propel-gen` as is described on the [Propel documentation](http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation#installing_dependencies) it fails with the error:

```
./propel-gen: line 69: phing: command not found
```

However if I check to see if phing is installed it doesn't appear in the package list, yet if I try to install it again it fails:

```
$ pear list
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.8   stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1   stable
Log              1.12.7  stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable

$ pear install phing/phing
phing/phing is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.4.7.1 install failed
```

I need to be able to run `./propel-gen` to test that Propel has been installed successfully, so I'm a little stuck at this point. I've also double checked that Pear is in the PHP `include_path` by running the following which exits `bool(true)`:

```
<?php
    require_once 'System.php';
    var_dump(class_exists('System', false));
?>
```

Any help in debugging & fixing this is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What OS are you using for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have pear's bin (executable) directory in your `$PATH` variable.

Find the path with

```
$ pear config-get bin_dir
```

Add this to your path that way:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/php/bin
```