# propel-gen: command not found

Tags: propel

Im having trouble using Propel to generate my models. On my work project the server admin installed the propel pear module so I can use propel-gen to do this. Ive followed the same route for my own project but Im having issues getting the propel-gen command to work

Im using MAMP. I use instructions found here: http://www.propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation

```
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:/ azz0r$ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:/ azz0r$ which pear
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:/ azz0r$ pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
Channel "pear.phing.info" is already initialized
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:/ azz0r$ sudo pear install phing/phing
Password:
phing/phing is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.4.12
install failed
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:/ azz0r$ sudo pear install Log
pear/Log is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.12.7
install failed
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:/ azz0r$ cd /Users/azz0r/Sites/Personal\ GIT/wuggawoo/library/ORM 
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$ sudo propel-gen yaml
Password:
sudo: propel-gen: command not found
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$
```

and

```
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$ sudo pear channel-discover pear.propelorm.org
Channel "pear.propelorm.org" is already initialized
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$ sudo pear install -a propel/propel_generator
propel/propel_generator is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.7
install failed
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$ sudo pear install -a propel/propel_runtime
propel/propel_runtime is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.7
install failed
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$ sudo propel-gen
sudo: propel-gen: command not found
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:ORM azz0r$ propel-gen
-bash: propel-gen: command not found
```

Are there any other ways to get this working?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7966853/569101) ?

Comment: This seems to work temporarily. However once I close terminal and reopen it, its forgotten that it works

Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:~ azz0r$ propel-gen
-bash: propel-gen: command not found
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:~ azz0r$ pear config-get bin_dir
/Users/azz0r/pear/bin
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:~ azz0r$ export PATH=$PATH:/Users/azz0r/pear/bin
Aaron-Wuggawoos-MacBook-Pro:~ azz0r$ propel-gen
Buildfile: /Users/azz0r/pear/data/propel_generator/pear-build.xml

propel-project-builder > projdircheckExists:

Comment: This isn't a propel problem then. You should search why PATH isn't kept when you close your terminal.