# propel-gen: command not found (phing)

Tags: php, installation, pear, propel, phing

I've installed the Propel ORM in my Zend Framework project with the following commands:

> pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
>   pear install phing/phing
>   pear install Log

But always when I try to run `propel-gen` I get the following error:

> propel-gen: command not found

I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966759/phing-installed-but-not-found-and-not-in-pear-list/7966853#7966853) post on stackoverflow and tried the following:

- When I check `$ pear list` I get the following:
   
  [image]
- When I run the following command:

  pear config-get bin_dir

  I get this: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin
- I've checked my .bash_profile:

  PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH

  export PATH

I assume that this is correct?

I forgot to install propel but when I want to load the command

> propel-gen om

I get the following erros:

[image]

(build.properties and schema.xml are in the same directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually installed `phing` and not `propel`. To [install `propel`](http://pear.propelorm.org/) issue the following commands:

```
pear channel-discover pear.propelorm.org 
pear install -a propel/propel_generator
pear install -a propel/propel_runtime
```

Further note that you have to pass the `-a` option to `pear list` to see packages from all channels:

```
pear list -a
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error when I want to load the propel-gen om command ... Updated begin post

Comment: Ok, at least propel is installed now (as it looks). Now it is missing some libraries.. Hard to say from here what exactly is missing. You'll have to debug that an install proper packages

Comment: Yes, but the strange thing is he can't find it but when I check it manually it's there ...

Comment: Then something with the `include_path` is wrong. Have you manipulated it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is my include path: include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/ZendFramework/library:/usr/lib/php/pear"

Comment: I guess you are using mysql. Where is that mysqlPlatform.php file stored on disk?

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/data/propel_generator/lib/platform . Could this have something do with my .bash_profile, that I maybe have to include something in my path?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35771/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-niels123)

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see where you have done this

```
pear channel-discover pear.propelorm.org
pear install -a propel/propel_generator
pear install -a propel/propel_runtime
```

Assume you have ?

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error when I want to load the propel-gen om command ... Updated begin post